# How can I install openssh-server without openssh-client on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, software-installation, openssh

I'm trying to install openssh-server on a Ubuntu server 20.04. When I try to install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

the process wants to install openssh-client, openssh-sftp-server and ssh-import-id. If I proceed and try to remove openssh-client, openssh-server and the other packages are removed too.

Is there a way to install openssh-server only?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? IIRC some connections involve launching the client on the server with a different set of arguments (e.g. scp), so this will definitely break functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`openssh-server` has a dependency on `openssh-client`.  That means the client is needed by the server.  You will need to install the client.  I would like to show you the full list of dependencies, but I do not have 20.04 installed, yet.  Try this command:

`less /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages`

Then type in `/Package: openssh-server` to find the section for `openssh-server`.  Then look for the `Depends:` line just below that.  It should show you what packages it depends on.

Comment: You don't need to do all that. Either `apt-cache depends openssh-server` or the package index (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openssh-server) is enough.